# How do I add modules, binaries or scripts to initramfs in RHEL distributions?

Tags: rhel, boot, initramfs

I have an initramfs script I developed for Debian distributions that required some extra binaries to be loaded into the image. I'm now trying to port this to RHEL distributions and I'm struggling.

To add binaries to initramfs on Debian I'd use a hook script at `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/`. I could then place the script at `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/`. An extra module can be loaded with a quick `echo my_module >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules`

This is all picked up by a subsequent `update-initramfs` and injected into the subsequent image.

The location of these files on the image is revealed by an `lsinitramfs`. The script finds its way to `/scripts/init-bottom/` and the binaries appear in `/bin/`. However, `lsinitrd` on CentOS doesn't reveal a `/scripts/` folder or an equivalent.

I see that I can use `dracut` to load and extra module and even load extra binaries (this time in `/usr/bin/`) but it's not clear how or where I should install the script.

How should I install modules, binaries or scripts to initramfs in RHEL distributions?

Comment: What version of RHEL/CentOS are you using?

Comment: I've been working with CentOS 7 though I'd have use for it on CentOS 6.5 as well. Thanks for your interest.